# Javascript function multiply calling

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is code

```
    function CreateArray(length) {
    var array1 = [];
    for (var k = 0, t = length; k < t; k++) {
        array1.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 3000000))
    };
    return array1;

}
    var array = CreateArray(100,500,1000) // works only for 100
```

It looks like i think a stupid question, but i'm stuck at calling of a function. How to call this function with different lengths?

Comment: Do you mean you want to return *multiple* arrays with a single call of the function?

Comment: `[100,500,1000].map(CreateArray)`?

Comment: Yea, i want to return multiply arrays with one calling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use rest parameters in the argument, and `map` each length to a new array of randoms:

```js
const CreateArray = (...lengths) => lengths.map(length => (
  Array.from({ length }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000000))
));
const [arr1, arr2, arr3] = CreateArray(100, 500, 1000);
console.log(arr2.length);
console.log(arr2[10]);
```

Comment: i think that is not for me, cuz after function of CreateArray, i'm going into insertion sort, and after that i want just with one calling check all the lengths, like this insertionSort(array.slice());

Comment: Why would that make a difference? You can do whatever you want to with the returned arrays. It returns three arrays with one call, isn't that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Return multiply arrays with one calling :

**Solutions :**

```js
function CreateArray(length) {
    var array1 = [];
    for (var k = 0, t = length; k < t; k++) {
        array1.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 3000000))
    };
    return array1;

}

//var array = CreateArray(100,500,1000);

var arrayArguments= [100, 500, 1000],
    resultArray = arrayArguments.map(function(num) {
    return CreateArray(num);
});
console.log(resultArray);
```

Hope it's helpful :)